# Why isn't my React Hook updating when I setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using react `useState`, where the state is an object with some nested properties. When I call `setState` on it, I'm not seeing a re-render or the state being updated. I assume react is seeing that the new state equals the old state and so no updates occur. So, I've tried cloning the state first, but still am not seeing any updates.

How can I get this function to cause the state to update?

```
export type TermEditorStateRecord = {
  term: SolrTermType;
  state: SolrTermEditorRecordState;
  classifications: { [key: string]: string };
};

export type TermEditorStateRecordMap = {
  [phrase: string]: TermEditorStateRecord;
};

const [records, setRecords] = useState({});

const setRecordClassification = (label, key, value) => {
  const cloned = new Object(records) as TermEditorStateRecordMap;
  cloned[label].classifications[key] = value;
  setRecords(cloned);
};
```

I apologize for the TypeScript types, but I've included them here so that you can see the expected shape of the state.

Is it not updating because the changes are deeply nested? Is there a way to get this to work, or do I need to somehow pull the state that changes out into its own state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Object` does not make a deep copy, so for `setRecords` it's the same instance and it won't trigger the re-render,

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: "b"
  }
};

const copy = new Object(obj);

copy["c"] = "c";

console.log(obj);
```

You'll need to manually updated the nested property :

```
const setRecordClassification = (label, key, value) => {
  setRecords(record => ({
    ...record,
    [label]: {
      ...record[label],
      classifications: {
        ...record[label].classifications,
        [key]: value
      }
    }
  }));
};
```

or to create a copy, use :

```
const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(record));
cloned[label].classifications[key] = value;
setRecords(cloned);
```